# The location of documents in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, sharding

I have a question about ElasticSearch.

Let's say I do the indexing like the following

PUT /vehicles/car/123
{
"make": "Honda",
"Color": "Black",
"HP": 250,
"milage": 24000,
"price": 19300.97
}

Please advise where this new document will be physically stored at.

I saw some online information saying that documents are stored at Shard.

But shard also contains multiple "segments", where a segment is an inverted index.

Does it mean shard stores both documents and segments at the same time?  Please correct my concept if needed

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An elasticsearch index is made up of multiple shards, where each shard is a Lucene index. A Lucene index is made up of multiple index segments.

> Does it mean shard stores both documents and segments at the same
> time?

Well, the shards store documents yes. But shard (which is a Lucene Index) itself is made up of multiple index segments, which will actually store the inverted index data structure.